# Multiple Actors as Buttons - detecting which one is touched/clicked

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx

I have a screen with 8 different static buttons on it. I have written a class to make this easy:

```
public class TouchButton extends Actor{
    Texture texture;
    float actorX, actorY;
    int actorWidth, actorHeight;
    public boolean started = false;

    public TouchButton(String argButtonID, float argActorX, float argActorY, int argWidth, int argHeight){

        String file = argButtonID;
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(file));
        this.actorX = argActorX;
        this.actorY = argActorY;
        this.actorWidth = argWidth;
        this.actorHeight = argHeight;

        setBounds(actorX, actorY, argWidth, argHeight);
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((TouchButton)event.getTarget()).started = true;

                Gdx.app.debug("BUTTON", "pressed" );

                Gdx.input.vibrate(100);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
         batch.draw(texture,actorX,actorY,this.actorWidth, this.actorHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        if(started){
            actorX+=5;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I am writing out a message to the LogCat, but I have been unable to work out how to determine which of the buttons was pressed.

In my game, a bit like "simon", I wish to display a colour or shape, and then get the player to click the correct colour matching button - so I will need to know which button they have pressed.

My buttons are instantiated as follows, my main Game Screen which Implements Screen.

```
    purpleButton = new TouchButton("shapes/purple.jpg", 0.0f, stage.getHeight() - 256, 256, 256);
    purpleButton.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    stage.addActor(purpleButton);

    pinkButton = new TouchButton("shapes/pink.jpg", stage.getWidth() - 256, 0.0f, 256, 256);
    pinkButton.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    stage.addActor(pinkButton);
```

Any help would be appreciated here.

How can I listen in my main game class for these button touch events, and determine which one was pressed?

Many Thanks

James

Comment: Is Actor is extended form View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a identifier index as a parameter when creating your TouchButton object.

Then when a button is pressed simply set the static int lastPressIndex to the index of the button being pressed.

```
public TouchButton(String argButtonID, float argActorX, float argActorY, int argWidth, int argHeight, int buttonIndex)
```

Define a static variable representing the button that was pressed:

```
public static int lastPressIndex = 0;
```

Then in your game loop (render method) you could check the value of *lastButtonPressIndex* and see which button pass pressed by it's index.

Your TouchButton class would look something like this:

```
public class TouchButton extends Actor{
    Texture texture;
    float actorX, actorY;
    int actorWidth, actorHeight;
    public boolean started = false;
    private int buttonIndex = 0; // New stuff

    public static int lastPressIndex = 0; // New stuff/

    public TouchButton(String argButtonID, float argActorX, float argActorY, int argWidth, int argHeight, int buttonIndex){ // new parameter

        String file = argButtonID;
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(file));
        this.actorX = argActorX;
        this.actorY = argActorY;
        this.actorWidth = argWidth;
        this.actorHeight = argHeight;
        this.buttonIndex = buttonIndex; // new stuff

        setBounds(actorX, actorY, argWidth, argHeight);
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((TouchButton)event.getTarget()).started = true;

                Gdx.app.debug("BUTTON", "pressed" );
                TouchButton.lastPressIndex = this.buttonIndex; // new stuff
                Gdx.input.vibrate(100);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
         batch.draw(texture,actorX,actorY,this.actorWidth, this.actorHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        if(started){
            actorX+=5;
        }
    }
}
```

When creating your TouchButton instances you simply keep track of which button belongs to which index. A HashMap would be the way to go.

```
HashMap<Integer, TouchButton) holdsButtons = new HashMap<Integer, TouchButton>();

holdsButtons.put(1, new TouchButton("shapes/purple.jpg", 0.0f, stage.getHeight() - 256, 256, 256, 1)); // Created the TouchButton and made a relation between the object and an Integer value, in this case 1.
```

in your render method:

```
public void render() {
   if(TouchButton.lastPressIndex > 0) { // Making sure a button is actually pressed.
        TouchButton pressedButton = holdsButtons.get(TouchButton.lastPressIndex);
        // Now you know which button was pressed.
        TouchButton.lastPressIndex = 0; // Reset the value.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the great answer. I do however have an error with the line 

    TouchButton.lastPressIndex = this.buttonIndex; // new stuff

As it says it "cannot resolve symbol 'buttonIndex'". 

Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: Update your code in your question so that i can see your code as it is now and we'll figure it out.@doneByDesign